# Why can't I add the remote option to my form_for helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm simply trying to add `remote: true` to a form_form helper:

```
<%= form_for (@user, remote: true) do |form| %>
    <%= form.email_field :email, placeholder: "email" %>
    <%= form.password_field :password, placeholder: "password" %>
    <%= form.submit "Create User" %>
<% end %>
<ul id="users">
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <li><%= user.email %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

However, the server keeps returning a syntax error, citing the comma:
`syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'`

Looking at the example in the [documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#built-in-helpers), I don't see what I doing differently:

```
<%= form_for(@article, remote: true) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space between from_for and (.